# Prove that the minimal finitely axiomatizable theory of arithmetic $\mathbf{Q}$ plus the Rosser sentence is consistent.

Tags: logic, incompleteness, metalogic

> Let $T$ be $\mathbf{Q}$ (which is a minimal finitely axiomatized theory of arithmetic). Let $R$ be the Rosser sentence of $T$. Let $T_0$ be $T + \{R \}$ and $T_1$ be $T + \{\sim R\}$. Show that $T_0$ and $T_1$ are both consistent. Show that $T_0 \cup T_1$ is inconsistent.

For reference, the Rosser sentence of $T$ is:

\begin{align*}
  \vdash_T R &\leftrightarrow \forall y ( \text{Prf}_T ( \ulcorner R \urcorner, \mathbf{y}) \to \exists z < y (\text{Disprf}_T(\ulcorner R \urcorner, \mathbf{z}))) \\  
\end{align*}

The last part is quite easy. $T_0 \cup T_1$ has both $R$ and $\sim R$ so it's inconsistent.

However, we can prove that the Rosser sentence is undecidable in $\mathbf{Q}$ or any consistent, finitely axiomatizable extension of $\mathbf{Q}$.

To quickly review the proof that the Rosser sentence is not provable in any consistent, finitely axiomatizable extension of $\mathbf{Q}$: Suppose the Rosser sentence is provable, then there is some natural number that serves as a witness for its provability and by the Rosser sentence such that there is an earlier witness for its disprovability which yields a contradiction. Hence, the Rosser sentence is not provable.

$T_0$ is $T + \{R\}$. That is a finitely axiomatizable extension of $\mathbf{Q}$. Therefore, based on the proof we just reviewed, it must be inconsistent, and it seems to produce a refutation of the assigned problem, rather than a solution.

Comment: I'm not following why the second to last paragraph implies $T_0$ is inconsistent. In fact, "the Rosser sentence is undecidable over $T$" means exactly that $T_0$ and $T_1$ are both consistent.

Comment: Assuming I'm reading your thoughts right, your error is this: "$T$ does not prove $R$" does not mean "$T+R$ is inconsistent", it means "$T+\lnot R$ is consistent".

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen, if $T$ is a consistent, axiomatizable extension of $\mathbf{Q}$ then the Rosser sentence is undecidable, meaning neither $R$ nor $\lnot R$ is provable in $T$. The contrapositive of that says that If $R$ or $\lnot R$ is provable in some theory $T$, then the theory isn't a consistent, axiomatizable extension of $\mathbf{Q}$. If $T_0$ is $T + \{R\}$, such that $R$ is a theorem in $T$, then $\vdash_T R$ such that $R$ is provable in $T$ and therefore $T$ is not consistent.

Comment: If $T_1$ is $\mathbf{Q} + \{ \lnot R\}$ I presume that means the theory axiomatized by the axioms of $\mathbf{Q}$ and $\lnot R$. Then $\vdash_{T_1} \lnot R$ which means that $R$ is disprovable and therefore decidable or not undecidable and therefore by the contrapositive mentioned earlier, $T_1$ is inconsistent.

Comment: The last sentence of your first comment doesn't make sense. Why does $\vdash_T R$ hold (even under the assumption that $T +\{R\}$ is consistent)? The second comment's error is easier to pinpoint: There is nothing wrong with $T_1$ proving $\lnot R.$ $R$ is $T$'s Rosser sentence, not $T_1$'s.

Comment: Reading back, maybe that last thing is the whole issue. There is not just one Rosser sentence. There is a different Rosser sentence for each theory (taking the same schematic form but using the proof and disproof predicates particular to the theory). What's true is that any consistent, finitely axiomatizable extension of $\mathbf Q$ can't decide *its own* Rosser sentence.

Comment: I meant to write: If $T_0$ is $T + \{R\}$ such that $R$ is a theorem in $T_0$, then $\vdash_{T_0} R$ such that $R$ is provable in $T_0$ and therefore $T_0$ is not consistent.

As for the second error, thank you. A consistent $T_0$ can't prove/disprove its own Rosser sentence, that doesn't hold for a Rosser sentence in another theory. thank you.

Comment: ok, so my refutation is wrong. How do I prove that $T_0$ is consistent and there is no sentence $A$ such that both $\vdash_{T_0} A$ and $\vdash_{T_0} \lnot A$?

Comment: If $T+\{R\}\vdash A\land \lnot A,$ then by the deduction theorem, $T\vdash R\to (A\land\lnot A)$, which is logically equivalent to $\lnot R,$ so $T\vdash \lnot R,$ which is false since $R$ is $T$'s Rosser sentence. In general, a good fact to commit to memory is that if $B$ is any sentence, $T$ doesn't prove $B$ if and only if $T+\{\lnot B\}$ is consistent.

Comment: That's the solution. I understand it. Thank you!

Comment: Would you prefer this thread be answered or closed/deleted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answered this in the comments, but will recap in an answer:

- There is not one Rosser sentence $R,$ but rather a different Rosser sentence $R_T$ for each theory. These all take the form you write down, but the definition of the $\mathrm{Prf}_T$ and $\mathrm{Disprf}_T$ formulas depend on the theory $T.$ If $T$ is a consistent, recursive extension of $\mathbf Q,$ the Rosser sentence $R_T$ is not decidable from $T$, but this doesn't mean it can't be decidable from some consistent, recursive extension $T_0$ of $T.$
- As for how to do the problem, if $T+\{R\}$ were inconsistent, we would have $T+\{R\}\vdash A\land\lnot A$ for some $A,$ and then by the deduction theorem, $T\vdash R\to (A\land \lnot A).$ But, by truth tables, $R\to (A\land \lnot A)$ is logically equivalent to $\lnot R,$ so $T\vdash R,$ which is impossible since $R$ is $T$'s Rosser sentence. The same argument works to show that $T+\{\lnot R\}$ is consistent.

All the work in the second bullet is in proving a theorem so frequently used that it is worth caching in memory:

> If $T$ is any theory and $A$ is any sentence in its language, then $T+\{A\}$ is inconsistent if and only if $T\vdash \lnot A.$

So once that fact is in hand, the argument is just: "Since $T\nvdash R,$ $T+\{\lnot R\}$ is consistent, and since $T\nvdash \lnot R, $ $T+\{R\}$ is consistent."